# Can I join my neighbor on Minecraft PE if we have different internet providers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If my friend is a few blocks down the road. Would I be able to join her? We are on two different wifi networks, but we share the same provider (Verizon, AT&T, etc.). Would we be able to join each other?

Answer (score 2):

No, sadly. My cousin experienced this when he got pocket edition. Players have to be on the same wifi network to play together (he tried to play with a buddy who was in another town, but it wouldn't let him)